# Can a redux reducer return properties of the old state as part of the new state?

Tags: redux

Let's say I have this state:

```
state: {
  field1: value1,
  field2: {a: 5, b: 7}
}
```

If a reducer wants to **update only `field1`**, can the reducer return a new object containing a new `field1` and the existing object `state.field2` as `field2` property of the new returned state? Or does the reducer have to clone field2?

Comment: Note that my question is NOT how to make a copy of an object, but WHETHER it is acceptable for a reducer to return properties of the old state which are objects or arrays as properties of the new state. This does not mutate the old state, but it recycles it kind of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Not only is recycling state permissible, it's *recommended*.

Say your initial state is:

```
{
  object1: { /* key-pair values */ },
  object2: { /* key-pair values */ },
}
```

If you update your state like this:

```
// bad
return {
  object1: action.object1,
  object2: Object.assign({}, state.object2),
}
```

Then your app thinks `object2` has changed even when it hasn't. This may cause unnecessary calculations and re-renders in your React components.

It's much better to only update the parts of your state that have actually changed.

```
// good
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  object1: action.object1,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use spread operator

```
return {
 ...state, 
 field1: newVal
}
```

Here is the link detailed immutable update patterns

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign()` is what you are looking for, now you can also use the spread operator (...) , but be aware that those are ES6 features, so something like internet explorer (even 11) will crash at both , so you will need a polyfill, check this link it will give  you more infos about it and also a polyfill for older browsers
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign

```
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { b: 3 , c:2 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);

console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 3 , c: 2 }
```

hope it helps